# distribute by sort by /cluster by clear cut idea

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I'm not getting a clear cut idea about distribute by sort by /cluster by in hive

according to my understanding ,multiple reducers are used when we use distribute by sort by /cluster by in hive, so that sorting happens faster

but why is that the reducers are needed in sorting of columns ,sorting can be done by a map and it does not involve any aggregate function

does it have any relation with clustered by sorted by that we use when we create a table

the problem I'm facing is,

**select * from order_items cluster by order_item_order_id limit 10;**

for the above query ,reducer count is not changed even though i use the command,
**set mapreduce.job.reduce=4**

it still remains 1

[you can see here ,even though your change reducer count ,it still remains 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE3Qa.png)

though there is a post related to this , the answer given there does not clear my doubts..
thanks in advance....

Comment: `Distribute by` already implies using reducers. `cluster by` = distribute + sort.  'mapred.reduce.tasks' is correct property.

Comment: I didn't get you , can you please elaborate, "map" does the action of filtering and sorting ,so why we need reducer here.. in the given link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6r2jNcisRLw" they've used mapreduce.job.reduce to increase the reducer count.can u point me where i'm going wrong..

Comment: he used mapreduce.job.reduces, you mapreduce.job.reduce